# How to wait for unknown number of processes to end

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization

**The scenario:**

There are several processes running on a machine. Names and handles unknown, but they all have a piece of code running in them that's under our control.

A command line process is run. It signals to the other processes that they need to end (SetEvent), which our code picks up and handles within the other processes.

**The goal:**

The command line process needs to *wait* until the other processes have ended. How can this be achieved?

All that's coming to mind is to set up some shared memory or something and have each process write its handle into it so the command line process can wait on them, but this seems like so much effort for what it is. There must be some kernel level reference count that can be waited on?

**Edit 1:**

I'm thinking maybe assigning the processes to a job object, then the command line processes can wait on that? Not ideal though...

**Edit 2:**

Can't use job objects as it would interfere with other things using jobs. So now I'm thinking that the processes would obtain a handle to some/any sync object (semaphore, event, etc), and the command line process would poll for its existance. It would have to poll as if it waited it would keep the object alive. The sync object gets cleaned up by windows when the processes die, so the next poll would indicate that there are no processes. Not the niceset, cleanest method, but simple enough for the job it needs to do. Any advance on that?

Comment: Use a named pipe for your client processes to communicate either their process ID or duplicated process handle, and have the server process wait on all those process handles. A process handle gets signaled irrespective of how a process terminates (normal suhutdown, crash).

Comment: `maybe assigning the processes to a job object` vs `handles unknown`. how is process created ? all at once ? or during time can be created new processes ?

Comment: @RbMm Handles unknown to the command line process. The processes themselves can know their own handle and add themselves to a job object. The user is free to run and terminate these processes freely.

Comment: @parrowdice - we can assume that process not crash, hang, etc ? or not? and `they all have a piece of code running in them that's under our control.` - so you control not all process behavior, but say have own dll in it ? or whole process under our control ?

Comment: @RbMm Safer to assume that the processes may terminate unexpectedly. Whole processes are actually under our control, but from the perspective of the command line process we don't know their handles or names.

Comment: @parrowdice - exist good solution by using shared section and one common event. but this assume that all processes will be correct working with shared memory (increment/decrement value) and last process set event. so processes must not hung, or terminated external

Comment: Why are you complicating this? All you need in your server is the process IDs/handles. So set up a named pipe (using a statically allocated GUID as the name, for example), have the client processes communicate their IDs/handles back, and be done with it. Everything else is handled by the OS (namely signaling process handles once they terminate).

Comment: @IInspectable: Setting up a named pipe to communicate handles seems much more complicated to me than querying a kernel object's existance (although I agree it is a cleaner solution). This work is being done by an apprentice, and getting the whole pipe mechanism working is far more advanced than "CreateEvent", "OpenEvent".

Comment: You can't ask for a reliable solution and then come back to inform us, that your apprentice isn't up to the task, so you'd rather go with something easy, that doesn't meet the requirements. Polling for the existence of a waitable object is an outrageously misguided anti-pattern.

Comment: @IInspectable: You are entirely correct :D. My poor apprentice is going to have a nice learning curve with this one. It seems like there should be a much simpler solution, but it seems like sharing the handles is the only correct way.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't think it's as simple as that, because if I understand correctly the control process doesn't exist when the subordinate processes are launched.  They could connect to a named pipe when the event object is signaled, but how is the control process to know how many subordinate processes need to check in?

Answer (score 2):

You can do either of following ways.

**Shared Memory (memory mapped object)** : CreateFileMapping, then  MapViewOfFile --> Proceed the request. UnmapViewFile. Close the file,

**Named Pipe** : Create a nameed pipe for each application. And keep running a thread to read the file. So, You can write end protocol from your application by connecting to that named pipe. ( U can implement a small database as like same )

**WinSock** : (Dont use if you have more number of processes. Since you need to send end request to the other process. Either the process should bind to your application or it should be listening in a port.)

**Create a file/DB** : Share the file between the processes. ( You can have multiple files if u needed ). Make locking before reading or writing.

Comment: Thank you. All seem valid, but still all feel like overkill to me. Maybe I'm wanting too much (/too little)?

Comment: If you are looking in windows application api ( Like Desktop application ) you can use **SendMessage**. 
example : `YourProcess[] = Process.GetProcessesByName("testProcess.exe");
SendMessage(YourProcess[1].MainWindowHandle, CLOSE_APP_PROTOCOL, NULL, NULL); `
You will receive the CLOSE_APP_PROTOCOL in your testProcess.

Comment: 1. That doesn't look like C++, but it does demonstrate your intention. 2. Signaling to close the processes isn't an issue, we can use SetEvent for that. 3. We don't know the process names or handles from the command line process

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a solution using two objects:

- a shared semaphore object, created by the main (controller?) app, with an initial count of 0, just before requesting the other processes to terminate (calling `SetEvent()`) - I assume that the other processes don't create this event object, neither they fail if it has not been created yet.
- a mutex object, created by the other (child?) processes, used not for waiting on it, but for allowing the main process to check for its existence (if all child processes terminate it should be destroyed). Mutex objects have the distinction that can be "created" by more than one processes (according to the documentation).

Synchronization would be as follows:

- The child processes on initialization should create the Mutex object (set initial ownership to `FALSE`).
- The child processes upon receiving the termination request should increase the semaphore count by one (`ReleaseSemaphore()`) and then exit normally.
- The main process would enter a loop calling `WaitForSingleObject()` on the semaphore with a reasonably small timeout (eg some 250 msec), and then check not whether the object was granted or a timeout has occurred, but whether the mutex still exists - if not, this means that all child processes terminated.

This setup avoids making an interprocess communication scheme (eg having the child processes communicating their handles back - the number of which is unknown anyway), while it's not strictly speaking "polling" either. Well, there is some timeout involved (and some may argue that this alone is polling), but the check is also performed after each process has reported that it's terminating (you can employ some tracing to see how many times the timeout has actually elapsed).

Comment: I don't think this is significantly better than simple polling, because when the last subordinate process calls `ReleaseSemaphore` the mutex will still exist.  So you'll always have to wait for the timeout to occur, and you might as well just be sleeping 250 msec in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach: you already have an event object that every subordinate process has open, so you can use that.  After setting the event in the master process, close the handle, and then poll until you discover that the event object no longer exists.

**The better approach:** named pipes as a synchronization object, as already suggested.  **That sounds complicated, but it isn't.**

The idea is that each of the subordinate processes creates an instance of the named pipe (i.e., all with the same name) when starting up.  There's no need for a listening thread, or indeed any I/O logic at all; you just need to create the instance using [CreateNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx), then throw away the handle without closing it.  When the process exits, the handle is closed automatically, and that's all we need.

To see whether there are any subordinate processes, the master process would attempt to connect to that named pipe using [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).  If it gets a file not found error, there are no subordinate processes, so we're done.

If the connection succeeded, there's at least one subordinate process that we need to wait for.  (When you attempt to connect to a named pipe with more than one available instance, Windows chooses which instance to connect you to.  It doesn't matter to us which one it is.)

The master process would then call [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) (just a simple synchronous read, one byte will do) and wait for it to fail.  Once you've confirmed that the error code is `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` (it will be, unless something has gone seriously wrong) you know that the subordinate process in question has exited.  You can then loop around and attempt another connection, until no more subordinate processes remain.

(I'm assuming here that the user will have to intervene if one or more subordinates have hung.  It isn't impossible to keep track of the process IDs and do something programmatically if that is desirable, but it's not entirely trivial and should probably be a separate question.)

Comment: This sounds like the way to do it. I'll go down this route and accept the answer if it works. Can't think of any reason why it wouldn't. Thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: No worries.  You can find my email address in my Stack Overflow profile, if you find this doesn't work as expected I'd be happy to look at a [mcve].